# Application path and listening port

Tags: linux, port, listen

I'd like to know which application that is listening on a port on a Linux machine.

There are multiple servers, [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) and what not on a single machine and I'd like to know which server is listening on which port without having to dig through the configuration files of each server.

Is there a command that lists the path to the executable and which port it is listening on?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`netstat -t -l -p` will list the listening ports and the pid and process name that created the socket. Since you have the pid you can use `ps PID` to find the path to the executable.

Comment: Run as root on some (all?) systems to get full info.

Comment: For completeness this command lists TCPIP ports. Use netstat -u -l -p for UDP.

Comment: If you are looking for a numeric port you may need to add `-n` parameter.
`netstat -t -l -p -n` will not resolve any names and will show everything in numeric format.

Answer (score 11):

Also `lsof -i:<port number>` should give you the PID of the process and you can use `ps <pid>` to look up for the path